# How to scan gray level image pixel by pixel and assign labels to pixels without using bwlabel?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a gray level image.i want to scan the image pixel by pixel from left to right and top to bottom using 8-neighbours.
I want to check how many neighbours are 1 or greater and what is the value of neighbour? I want to label the pixel based on the value of neighbours

```
[m n]=size(Img)
kernel = [-1 -1 -1; -1 8 -1; -1 -1 -1];
outputImage = conv2(I, kernel);
for i=1:m
 for j=1:n
   if(Img(I,j)==1) check neighbours
end
end
```

if I have an image as

D =

```
 1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     1     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0     0
```

no.of neighbours are counted as

neighbour=

```
 1     3     2     3     2     2
 3     2     3     3     3     2
 1     3     2     2     1     1
 2     4     2     3     1     1
 1     2     3     2     3     1
 1     1     2     1     3     1
```

Scan from left to right D(1,1)==1 and neighbour(1,1)>=1 So label it as 1 as no neighbours are labeld.if one of the neighbour labelled then copy it if more than one neighbous are labelled then copy one of the label and mark it as equivalent

I tried your code on this image

[image]

but all the labels are 1.but bwlabel produces a different result

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143463/discussion-on-question-by-user-how-to-scan-gray-level-image-pixel-by-pixel-and-a).

Answer (score 0):

First binarize your image with threshold 1

The apply the correct kernel, so the convolution will result in the number of "activated" neighbours

```
Img_binarized = double(Img >= 1);
kernel = [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1];
Img2 = conv2(Img_binarized, kernel);
% here each pixel of Img2 contains the number of neighbours >= 1
```

Comment: You have to specify in your question what do you actually want to do. Write a small example with a 5x5 matrix and tell us what you want to achieve. This answer tells you "how many neighbours are 1 or greater" which is your question.

Comment: Img=[1 0 1 0 1 0;0 1 0 1 0 1;1 0 1 0 1 0;0 1 1 0 1 0;1 0 0 1 0 1; 0 0 0 1 0 0];
img=double(Img);
Img_binarized = Img >= 1
kernel = [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1];
Img2 = conv2(Img_binarized, kernel);

Comment: Error using conv2
First and second arguments must be single or double.

Error in Untitled6 (line 5)
Img2 = conv2(Img_binarized, kernel);

Comment: Forget about it. You should edit your question and clearly explain what you are trying to achieve with an example. Any comments here will not be read or taken in account by anyone.

Comment: @ Sembei Norimaki updated question. your answer produces error

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki You need to cast `Img_binarized` to `double`.  `conv2` does not work with `logical` inputs.

Comment: @rayryeng can you help me to complete my algorithm

Comment: @rayryeng sure, but this is a minor thing. Updated my answer, however it doesn't seem what OP wants.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I agree.  I made that comment before I found out what the OP really wanted.